# Is there any tool for text steganography?

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack, steganography

i wanna ask anyone that know is there any tool or software to hide text in text it self, that we usually call it as text steganography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text steganography is by nature more difficult to do than image steganography, if high security is demanded. For good results one has to accept the trade-off of lower stego bit-rates, which could be practical for high-grade secrets which are as a rule of small volumes. I have two schemes of text steganography, see http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/6939954/1/ and http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7338098/1/ (I have searched quite a lot on the Internet but found nothing of like genre till the present.)